# How to deserialize an Event from IoT hub which it was passed to an Event-hub?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am processing a message from an **EventHub** connected with an **IoT Hub**. I will try to explain the whole process.

Using a terminal, I send the following command to an IoT hub component deployed on Azure:

```
  curl --request POST \
    --url "https://${IOT_HUB}.azure-devices.net/devices/${DEVICE}/messages/events?api-version=2018-06-30" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Authorization: ${SAS_TOKEN}" \
    --data "{ \"field1\" : \"12345\", \"field2\" : \"abcde\" }" \
    --verbose
```

When the Azure function receive the event (curl -> IoT hub -> Event-hub <- Azure Function) and print the content:

```
    @FunctionName("processSensorData")
    public void processSensorData(
            @EventHubTrigger(
                    name = "demo",
                    eventHubName = "", // blank because the value is included in the connection string
                    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
                    connection = "EventHubConnectionString")
                    String item,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Event hub message received: " + item.toString());
```

I receive the following message in the console:

```
    [
    {
       "id":"xxx",
       "topic":"/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/xxxPROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DEVICES/IOTHUBS/Txxxx",
       "subject":"devices/xxx",

   "eventType":"Microsoft.Devices.DeviceTelemetry",
   "eventTime":"2020-04-13T15:02:15.253Z",
   "data":{
      "properties":{

      },
      "systemProperties":{
         "iothub-content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
         "iothub-content-encoding":"",
         "iothub-connection-device-id":"xxx",
         "iothub-connection-auth-method":"{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}",
         "iothub-connection-auth-generation-id":"xxx",
         "iothub-enqueuedtime":"2020-04-13T15:02:15.253Z",
         "iothub-message-source":"Telemetry"
      },
      "body":"yyy"
   },
   "dataVersion":"",
   "metadataVersion":"1"
}]
```

but the body appear to be encrypted.

**How to decode the body to return the original request?**

```
"{ \"field1\" : \"12345\", \"field2\" : \"abcde\" }"
```

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body is base64 URL encoded. You should decode it in your code and then parse the JSON object out. Try this code for decoding:

```
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  var jsonStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should setup the system message properties such as the **contentType** to *application/json* and **contentEncoding** to *UTF-8* in your POST request.

Comment: I noticed that sending that header, the content of body appear in clear. Why Azure has that behaviour?

Comment: In the case of using JSON encoding for content (body), the message must set that *contentType* and *contentEncoding* system properties otherwise the body is in the base64 encoded format.